# Buying a pivot monitor, what to look for?

Tags: display, vesa

I recently fall in love with the double pivot(portrait) monitor setups for coding.

I checked monitors with pivot stands, which turned out to be unnecessarily expensive. I want to buy two basic monitors and use a vesa mount(s) to hold them in proper rotation.

When I did that with my own monitors, one IPS and one LED, both of them showed bad viewing angles and distorted colors at portrait mode.

Other than having vesa mount, what properties like viewing angles I need to look for buying new monitors for portrait usage?

I prefer technical answers telling me what specs to look for( and why ), rather than advises like "Buy this".

Thanks

Comment: LED is just backlight type, the matrix is probably [TN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_nematic_field_effect). It's the cheapest kind of LCD matrices with the worst viewing angles. IPS shouldn't be affected by this problem, though.

Comment: Entirely ungeneral, and probably unhelpful but I'd suggest getting a model someone else has used vertically successfully ;p

Answer (score 2):

You should be looking at IPS as a starting point. Other than that, specs aren't going to help you.

Ultimately you've discovered for yourself that the sub-pixel design of regular monitors is optimized for landscape viewing. In portrait mode things just doesn't look as good. That's where monitors designed specifically for portrait configuration come in, and you pay premium for them.

However, before you give up on using a regular monitor, try running Microsoft's clear-type tool (*Adjust ClearType text* in the Start Menu) while in portrait configuration. You might be surprised how much better things look after that!

** EDIT **

Look at the sub-pixel design of this S-IPS display (nabbed the image from Wikipedia). It's optimized for viewing in one orientation:

[image: sub-pixel design example]

Comment: any advice for linux setup?

Answer (score 2):

The obivous thing to look for in this case is: [Viewing angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_angle).

One thing that is special for your use case is, that you will need to focus more on vertical viewing angle (which, in the case of a portrait oriented monitor, will be the 'de facto' horizontal viewing angle).

From the wikipedia link above:

> The viewing angle is measured from one direction to the opposite,
>   giving a maximum of 180° for a flat, one-sided screen. Some display
>   devices exhibit different behaviour in horizontal and vertical axis,
>   requiring users and manufacturers to specify maximum usable viewing
>   angles in both directions. Usually the screens are aligned and used to
>   facilitate **greater viewing angle in horizontal level**, and **smaller
>   angle in the vertical level**, should the two of them be different in
>   magnitude.

Also, from [this article](http://www.slrlounge.com/what-is-an-ips-monitor-understanding-ips-displays/), consider the size of your screen relative to viewing angle and viewing distance:

> IPS monitors will also show color and brightness shifts from edge to
>   edge depending on the quality of the display, **it will simply be less
>   than a standard TN display**. Here is the same illustration, this time
>   showing our Apple MacBook Pro 15″ Retina display at a standard viewing
>   distance. Notice that while the color shifting is more subtle, we
>   still see a significant amount of shifting in brightness from edge to
>   edge.

So I would definitely recommend you to look for a monitor with an IPS panel and as wide as possible  vertical viewing angle. Some modern displays will have very wide viewing angle up to 178° / 178° (for example on a Dell [U2414H](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&cs=19&sku=860-BBCG), which also has a very thin edge, enabling you to mount two of them very close to each other.

Comment: This is also a good answer, as max viewing angle is an important consideration too.

Comment: I already have two monitors. Phillips 226V4LAB (170o (H) / 160o (V)) and and AOC 23" - i2369V IPS( Horizontal: 178 Degrees (CR>10)
Vertical: 178 Degrees (CR>10) ).  Both of them function bad with terrible colors when at portrait mode. Do I need even greater angles? or something wrong with them?

Comment: @Halox there is no greater angle than 178°. Viewing them from the side would be impossible which would correspond to 180°. So you would probably have to test some options out to see if you can get a monitor that will work for you in portrait mode.